# Set dynamic asp:HyperLinkField

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a gridview that is filled when the page is loaded with a dataReader.

I can add a column with hyperlinks but I need the url to contain the GenCod that is dynamically added line by line to the gridView so each link sends to its detail page.

URL Example: http://localhost:50228/misesenventedetail.aspx?GenCod=9788416657544

How can i use the index or name of the column to get the GenCod?

```
<asp:GridView ID="aParaitre_GridView" runat="server" OnRowCommand="RowCommand" >
   <Columns>
     <asp:ButtonField buttontype="Image" CommandName="AjouterAuPanier" ImageUrl="~/Images/buy_this_logo.png" />
     <asp:HyperLinkField NavigateUrl="url+Parameter+GENCOD" Text="VoirDetail" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This GridView contains much more columns.

Getting Error: System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField has no DataBinding.

With the the following code:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField               
     NavigateUrl='<%# String.Format("~/misesenventedetail.aspx?GenCod={0}", Eval("GenCod"))%>'
     Text="Detail" 
     runat="server"
     />
```

I was hoping something like this would work

```
 <asp:HyperLinkField
     id="MyLink"
     NavigateUrl="~/misesenventedetail.aspx?GenCod<%= gencod %>"
     runat="server" />


  protected void RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
  {
     // Gets the index of the line (row) where we click
     int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

     GridViewRow ligneClick = aParaitre_GridView.Rows[index];

     // Gets GenCod from column 1
     var GenCod = ligneClick.Cells[1].Text;

     MyLink.NavigateUrl = string.Format("../mypage.aspx?id={0}", GenCod );

  }
```

Comment: I tried searching for similar solutions but none uses a gridview.

Comment: Getting Error: System.Web.UI.WebControls.HyperLinkField has no DataBinding.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

I was able to resolve my problem with this:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
DataNavigateUrlFields="GenCod" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~/misesenventedetail.aspx?GenCod={0}" Text="Voir Details"        
runat="server" />
```

StackOverflow is so great.